# Why doesn't the focus assist light get triggered on a flash connected via a Pocket Wizard TT1?

Tags: flash, autofocus, canon-5d, pocket-wizard, focus-assist

I have a Pocket Wizard TT1 and TT5 which work fine. I mount the TT1 on the camera shoe and the TT5 fires my remote flash ETTL fine.

I now want a focus assist light, so I set a flash (580, 430 or ST-E2) on the TT1 but there is no focus assist light.  If I put the flash directly on the shoe of the camera I get focus assist.

I measured the 5 leads on the shoe of the camera:

```
 1
2 3
4 5
```

1 - is the main lead, it is at 0 when autofocusing

2, 3, and 5 show up with a volt meter; 4 stays 0 when autofocusing.

Measuring the top of the TT1 none show any activity during autofocus.  I tried this on another TT1 and both had the same issue.  Has no one run into this? It's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was [tackled](http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?t=831387) some time ago in forum of Photography On The Net, where it was suggested that a test shot is needed before AF assist will start working.

Comment: At first I was like no way ... I took a couple of shots and the focus light still didn't work. Then I thought "well how can it set itself if there is no other flash?" I then hooked up the tt5 with a flash and yes but after another two shots the focus assist started working. I'll have to look into this, but my guess is there has to be another flash hooked up to the tt5 and fired before the the tt1 will set it's levels and then start firing the focus assist light. Thanks!